# Search and replace query for empty data

Tags: mysql, sql

I would to replace empty data in a field by the NULL value.

Extract of table record - 3 different type (Drupal 6 DB), I want the empty one (242) goes like the NULL one (156):

```
 INSERT INTO `content_field_lien_externe` (`vid`, `nid`, `delta`, `field_lien_externe_url`, `field_lien_externe_title`, `field_lien_externe_attributes`) VALUES
(10,    10, 0,  'http://www.onisep.fr', 'Lien ONISEP',  'a:0:{}'),
(156,   18, 3,  NULL,   NULL,   NULL),
(242,   219,    0,  '', NULL,   'a:0:{}');
```

and my query is:

```
 UPDATE `content_field_lien_externe`
 SET `field_lien_externe_url` = replace(field_lien_externe_url, '', 'NULL')
```

do nothing, so what is missing ?

thanks

Comment: Don't store the character string `'null'`... Set to the null-value instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` **is not a string**. Simply do `SET` null, `where` the field is empty.

Do the following (based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539905/search-and-replace-query-for-empty-data/52539992?noredirect=1#comment92020301_52539992)):

```
UPDATE `content_field_lien_externe`
 SET `field_lien_externe_url` = NULL, 
      `field_lien_externe_attributes` = NULL 
WHERE `field_lien_externe_url` = '' OR 
      `field_lien_externe_url` IS NULL
```

**Additionally:** Suppose you have string with only spaces in the `field_lien_externe_url` column. Then, still it can be considered as empty string, and you can use [Trim()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trim/) function, like below:

```
UPDATE `content_field_lien_externe`
 SET `field_lien_externe_url` = NULL, 
     `field_lien_externe_attributes` = NULL 
WHERE TRIM(field_lien_externe_url) = '' OR 
      `field_lien_externe_url` IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you're right, it's a value for the label,not for the data itself.

Comment: see my record extract to details.

Comment: @webmasterpf ya so my could should be doing exactly the same for `field_lien_externe_url` field

Comment: yes,it works but now I need to replace a:0:{} into field ``field_lien_externe_attributes``by NULL too,but only for field_lien_externe_url with NULL label value.

Comment: @webmasterpf check the updated answer. It will update `field_lien_externe_attributes` to null if `field_lien_externe_url` is null or empty